# AS2: Function not calling, using timer-- and myFunction();

Tags: function, actionscript, timer, actionscript-2

I'm programming a game for fun. I'm using a timer that when hits 0 it's supposed to call functions (which I think is how games work, right?). Anyway, myFunc; does not do anything at all when timer hits 0, but it does do timer = TIMER_INIT;.

Also, the first line below has myFunction; being called first thing and that also fails.

```
myFunction;

// Timer
var timer = TIMER_INIT;
countdown = function() {

    if (timer == 0) {
        myFunc ;
        timer = TIMER_INIT;
    } else {
            timer--; 
    }
}

countdownInterval = setInterval(countdown, TIMER_INTERVAL);

myFunc = function() {
    ab += abI;
    abc += abcI;
    abcd += abcdI;
    myFunction;
}

myFunction= function() {
    a.ab.text = ab + " / 200";
    a.abc.text = abc+ " / 200";
    a.abcd.text = abcd+ " / 200";   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't remember as2 at all , but may be you should try to call functions like this:

```
myFunction();
myFunc();
```

Comment: addind () indicate that you execute the function, without the (), it indicates that you add a pointer to the function (a function is a var). Its why it works with setInterval as it needs a function definition as first parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the () when you want to execute a function. Here is a working version of your code (I just added trace in each function so you can see what's happening)

```
myFunction();

// Timer
var timer = 10;
countdown = function() {
trace('countdown()');
    if (timer == 0) {
        myFunc() ;
        timer = 10;
    } else {
        timer--; 
    }
}

var countdownInterval = setInterval(countdown, 200);

myFunc = function() {
    trace('-->myFunc()');
    myFunction();
}

myFunction= function() {
    trace('-->myFunction()');
}
```